# Java - Is it possible to extend all the subclasses of a class with a single class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Java - Is it possible to extend all the subclasses of a class with a single class?

Let's explain it with an example, the actual code is quite more complex. I have an Animal class with its own class hierarchy. Let's say that it has two subclasses: Testarrosa and Viper.

```
public class Car {

    public abstract String getManufacturer();
}

public class Testarossa extends Car{

    public String getManufacturer(){
        return "Ferrari";
    }
}

public class Viper extends Car{

    public String getManufacturer(){
        return "Dodge";
    }
}
```

I want to extend all the Car subclasses with a RegisteredCar subclass.

```
public class RegisteredCar extends Car {

   private String plateNumber;

   public RegisteredCar (String plateNumber){
       this.plateNumber=plateNumber;
   }

   public String getPlateNumber() {
       return plateNumber;
   }
}
```

At some point, I should be able to create a new RegisteredCar of a specific subclass. Something like

```
RegisteredCar c = new RegisteredCar<Viper>("B-3956-AC");
```

And call the c.getManufacturer() to obtain "Dodge" and c.getPlateNumber() to obtain B-3956-AC. Obviously, I should still be able to create a `Car c = new Viper();`

That is an example. Having an attribute in Car with null value if not registered is not enough for what I need.

Comment: *"Let's say that it has two subclasses: Gorilla and Wolf"* .. I guess you should stick to your `Car` example ;).

Comment: but no, it can't be done.

Comment: Is it not possible to change the base class of Viper and Testarossa to RegisteredCar?

Comment: I don't see why a boolean member "registered" isn't enough.  Default behavior unregistered is taken care of with false value.  I would say using inheritance this way is a very bad design indeed.  I would say that using inheritance for makes is equally terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, no thats not really possible and your example could be solved by changing your model

As an alternative to inheritance you could use another class to wrap a `Car` instance.
I would make `Car` an interface (though having `RegisteredCar` extend `Car` should work too) and then attempt something like the following pseudo code:

```
class RegisteredCar<T extends Car> implements Car {
   private final  T car

   RegisteredCar(T car) {
     this.car = car;
   }

   ... methods for RegisteredCar
   ... methods from Car delegating to `this.car`
}
```

Please excuse the somewhat bad code, I don't have an IDE open, and I always mess up generics without an IDE to hand.

Another possible solution is to use AOP, though I don't know how in fashion that is these days as but what you are describing could be a cross cutting concern.

A final alternative might be to use a language that allows for Extensions, Traits, Protocol or some other type of 'mix in'

Comment: As I said to Bhushan, it's not perfect; but this is the best solution I found so far. Unfortunately, it must be Java :(

Comment: Thanks :).  Its not perfect but if you're restricted to Java sometimes you must deal with the the short comings of the language, no general purpose language is perfect.  Its a shame though as the JVM has some great languages with Java interop but it seems impossible to convince "leaders" to mix in a little of the other languages when its appropriate.  Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

In short, no that is not possible. You have to unfortunately modify your object model.

For example, what about having a `Registration` class this way:

```java
public interface Registration<C extends Car> {
    C getCar();

    String getPlateNumber();
}
```

This way you can extract the information relating to registration in a single class, while maintaining your `Car` models.

You can then do helper methods like:

```java
Registration<Viper> registeredViper = createRegistration(new Viper(), "B-3956-AC");
```

Comment: Ah! Almost the same as my answer.  I would just make it implement the `Car` interface then it can be used where `Car` was being used, just delegate the implemented methods to the wrapped `Car` instance.  Upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In java it is prohibited to extends more than 1 class.
You could build chain from classes to extends, for example.
To solve the problem of mutiple inheritance in Java → interface is used

Comment: It's not a problem of multiple inheritance. I'm not trying to create one class that inherits from multiple classes. It's a matter of a Generic inheritance; you don't know which class you are extending.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid inheritance as much as possible. Use abstractions (interfaces) to make your code elegant and **maintainable**. Just google *why extends is evil*.

```
    public interface Car{
        String getManufacturer();
    }

    public interface Registerable{
        boolean isRegistered();
        void    register(String plateNumber);
        void    getPlateNumber();
    }

    public class Viper implements Car, Registerable
    {
      //all methods
    }
```

Comment: Class inheritance is not evil at all. Your solution forces the programmer to implement the common methods in every subclass. How can that be maintainable?

Comment: If you need common functionality, you can implement that functionality, abstract it out and compose that abstraction to all classes that needs it. This way you will avoid dependency on implementation, you will be able to change implementation and nobody will notice that because implementation is completely hidden. This is called _Composition over inheritance_ . Small changes in superclass can ruin all subclasess or involve subtle bugs. Composition and dependency on abstractions helps to avoid such problems.

Comment: And that doesn't means the need to implement same methods over and over again. That means implementation of common functionality in one place, abstracting it and passing that abstraction to all classes that needs it.

Comment: @FrancescLordan I suggest you to read book _Holub on patterns_ . Despite its name, this book is real eyes opener. In my opinion it is a bible of modern OO design.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not like C++. Multiple inheritance is not possible in Java. However you can implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: It's not a problem of multiple inheritance. I'm not trying to create one class that inherits from multiple classes. It's a matter of a Generic inheritance; you don't know which class you are extending.

Answer (score 1):

With Generic class approach as described in other answer, you will not be able to use `RegisteredCar` where your require to pass `Car` object. e.g. suppose you need to generate some invoice.

```
Invoice getInvoice(Car c);
```

In this method you cannot use `RegisteredCar` as it is not of Type Car. All you API which require Car are not applicable to `RegisteredCar`. In some cases you may need Plate Number as well as Car, There you may need to keep mapping of Plate Number and Cars. I would suggest following approach based on Decorate Pattern and delegate all Car calls to passed car object

```
    public class RegisteredCar extends Car{

    public RegisteredCar(Car c, String plateNumber){

    }        
    @Override
    String getColor(){
       c.getColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the first part.
Although is not perfect since at the end you keep two different instances, and you need to call new Car() and new RegisteredCar(), it's a good workaround to a Java shortcoming. Parametrizing the class (Gavin's solution) goes a bit further for those methods that require specific subclass parameters, e.g. compareTo(Viper a).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that with inheritance. 
Your best option is making the RegisteredCar type generic, then having a generic instance variable that holds the intended type car:

```
public class RegisteredCar<T extends Car> {
   private String plateNumber;
   private T car;

   public T getCar() {
       return this.car;
   }
   public T setCar(T car) {
       this.car = car;
   }
   public RegisteredCar (String plateNumber){
       this.plateNumber=plateNumber;
   }
   public String getPlateNumber() {
       return plateNumber;
   }
}
```

With this, you will be able to pass into RegisteredCar an object of any type that's a subclass of Car.

As you can notice, I have removed the `extends Car` part of this class, as it doesn't need to be a subclass of car itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason, in the real classes, that you couldn't simply add the new feature to the existing base class?

```
public abstract class Car
{
    public abstract String getManufacturer() ;

    protected String plate_number = null ;

    public String getPlateNumber()
    { return this.plate_number ; }

    public boolean isRegistered()
    { return ( this.plate_number != null ) ; }
}
```